# Prevent redirecting page if the parameter is changed by the user

Tags: javascript, php

I am passing parameters in the url, my concern is what if the user changes the value of the parameter in the address bar. Is there a way/javascript where I can prevent the page from redirecting and give a warning instead? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if it is HTML then you can validate via js, suppose if it php page you must validate via PHP ex: if (!isset($_GET['para']) { }

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please explain more?Thanks